# Finding a graphical tool that's flexible in showing different geo info

Tags: c#, gui, maps

I am looking for a graphical tool for a C# application that can overlay markers on a map (Google Maps or whatever) and routes between markers (just a straight line between markers), and I want it to visually group markers with their route and visually distinguish different types of markers. Basically, a tool to show a solution for a VRP if you are familiar with that. Of course, the more interactive it is the better. The input to it would be latitude and longitude of markers, type of marker, list of markers on each route, and which routes and markers are grouped together.

Comment: What's wrong with the [Google maps API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve all your requirements using the Syncfusion ASP.NET Core Maps component. Find more information from the below links.

- Product page –
  https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-ui-controls/maps
- Demo samples
  – https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Maps/Default#/material
- UG
  Documentation –
  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/maps/getting-started-core